# Flash Virtual Gallery Alternative

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, flash-cs5, virtualstore

I have a requirement for the Flash Like Virtual Store, wherein, when the site loads, user will be shown with the Virtual Store, Full Screen Panaromic View, it would be playing like a video, once user clicks on any of the products from the store, that category will be loaded, this can be done in Flash, but i am no-vice in Flash, would like to know about any alternatives in jQuery.

Can we have something like above in jQuery or HTML5, can anyone provide me with the demo links for the same in jQuery or HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Image Armada uses WebGL (javascript). I have played with the demo and it seems pretty neat but have never used it personally. Nonetheless if you switch out paintings for any of your products it may serve as an option... Cheers.

http://www.imagearmada.co.uk/pages/index.php